# Right floated div floats in middle of the page until page render is complete

Tags: css

The page has a fluid layout, and a log in status div that is floated to the top right of the page.

The problem is that the element just sits in the center of the page until the page is fully rendered, at which point it moves to the correct position.

Presume this is because the browser doesn't know how big the containing div will be until it's rendered.

Is there a technique for dealing with this issue?

Here is the css for the div:

```
    div#headerLinks
{
    float: right;
    background: url('../Img/SomeImage.jpg') top left;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 14px 10px 15px;
    margin-right: -20px;
}
```

Comment: Are you seeing this behavior across browsers? How heavy of a page are you trying to load?

Comment: yeah, cross browsers. pretty heavy. Approx 300kb if no cache

Comment: You can always workaround it. With some javascript and jquerry. Keep showing a loading image until the document is ready or loaded. Hide the image and show the other divs.

Comment: In today's web, sadly, 300kb isn't that heavy, and other (much heavier) pages don't exhibit this behavior. Is the page content being generated dynamically every time? If so, are the structural parts of the page part of the generated content, or part of a static template file?

Comment: If your page is standard HTML + CSS, I don't see how any browser would behave like this unless you are relying on the CONTENT of the containing box to define its width (in other words, push it out). If the container has a width set, it should display immediately. If you're setting the width with JS, there could be a delay, but I'd find it very bizarre if straight CSS had a delay. Check the CSS on your containing elements.

Comment: The solution here is the 3rd comment - cheers liquid. If you add as an answer I will mark it as such.

Comment: @Cognize I added it as an answer. I'm glad I could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always workaround it, with some Javascript and jQuery.

Keep showing a loading image until the document is ready or loaded. 
Hide the image and show the other divs.

Code could look like this:

```
$(function () {
    onLoadContent();
});

function onLoadStatistics() {
    $(window).load(function () {
        $('#loading-image').hide();
        $('#content').show();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this turned out to be the best option, and is working well on the site. Seems to have increased overall render speed too.